# Facebook - How to show Authorisation box when going to app?

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization

How do I do this kind of login?

For example http://apps.facebook.com/badoocom => will show a automatic authorisation box

I tried with my app.

facebook settings "canvas and secure canvas is set to this page "index.php at my site.

but going to apps.facebook.com/xxxxx => shows a BLANK age

BUT if i run wwww.mysite.com/index.php it shows a authorisation box but NOT if i go to apps.facebook.com/myapp

index.php
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

```
if ($user) {
try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

if ($user) {
 $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
 } else {
  $params = array(
   'scope' => 'email,user_birthday',
   'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mysite.net/login_fb.php'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);


 header("Location: " . $loginUrl);
}
```

HTML code

```
echo "LOGGED IN";
more code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script language=javascript>";
echo "top.location.href ='".$loginUrl."';";
echo "</script>";
exit();
```

instead of

```
header($loginUrl);
```

worked